# C# - How to list listbox objects by name

Tags: c#, listbox

I have an Employee class that populates a listbox when I fill in text fields and click an add button. When the item gets added to the list it displays the object property and I need to figure out how to store the object in the list, but also list it by name.

**Here's my Employee class:**

```
class Employee
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Position;
        public DateTime BirthDate;
        public DateTime StartDate;
        public decimal Wage;

        public Employee(string name, string position, DateTime birthDate, DateTime startDate, decimal wage)
        {
            Name = name;
            Position = position;
            BirthDate = birthDate;
            StartDate = startDate;
            Wage = wage;
        }
    }
```

**Here is my button click event: (Where I populate the list)**

```
        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>();
            var name = txtName.Text;
            var position = txtPosition.Text;
            DateTime birthDate = dpBirthDate.Date.DateTime;
            DateTime startDate = dpStartDate.Date.DateTime;
            var wageValue = txtWage.Text;
            decimal wage = Decimal.Parse(wageValue);
            employees.Add(new Employee(name, position, birthDate, startDate, wage));
            foreach(Employee employee in employees)
            {
                lbEmployee.Items.Add(employee);
            }

        }
```

For the button click event in my for each loop I tried to list the object by doing this

```
foreach(Employee employee in employees)
    {
       lbEmployee.Items.Add(employee.Name);
    }
```

This lists it by name but doesn't add the entire object so it breaks the function below

```
private void lbEmployee_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Employee employee = (Employee)lbEmployee.SelectedItem;
            if (employee != null)
            {
                txtName.Text = employee.Name;
                txtPosition.Text = employee.Position;
                dpBirthDate.Date = employee.BirthDate;
                dpStartDate.Date = employee.StartDate;
                txtWage.Text = Convert.ToString(employee.Wage);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by break the function?

Comment: @viveknuna my guess would be that they get an expection when casting the selected item, since it is a string and not an `Employee`. @BAPTZ such casting never returns `null`, either it works or it throws an exception. You get only a null if you cast it by using: `lbEmployee.SelectedItem as Employee`

Comment: @MongZhu yes I agree with your point

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

```
lbEmployee.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

in the designer and then you can add the employee in the items avoiding to break  your function

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to coding. What is the designer? Do you mean the form editor?

Comment: @BAPTZ Yeah exactly

Comment: `<ListBox DisplayMember="Name"/>`
@Luca Q When I add `DisplayMember` it throws an error saying 'This property was not found in listbox'. I tried `DisplayMemberPath` but that just left the item in the listbox blank.

Comment: Do I have to set the class somewhere?